# how to set textarea height on auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, textarea

```js
var a = 'lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum ';
$('#btn').click(function(){
  $('#tx').val(a);
});
```

```css
#tx{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  background:gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='tx'>lorem</textarea>
<br>
<button id='btn'>CLICK</button>
```

So I need to see entire content inside a textarea, without hidden areas, just as in a div.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set height of textarea to height of scroll. So use `scrollHeight` property to getting it.

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
  $('#tx').val(a).height($("#tx")[0].scrollHeight)
});
```

```js
var a = 'lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum ';
$('#btn').click(function(){
  $('#tx').val(a+a+a).height($("#tx")[0].scrollHeight)
});
```

```css
#tx{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  background:gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='tx'>lorem</textarea>
<br>
<button id='btn'>CLICK</button>
```